# Area optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I'm having the requirement, to insert a specific amount of rectangles (which have a defined width but a random height) into another rectangle (which has a defined height and the same defined width as the rectangles to insert). The goal here is, that those inserted rectangles should fill-out the target rectangle as much as possible.

For instance:

[image]

I don't need to get as much rectangles as possible into the black, the goal is to fillout the black rect as much as possible, best case, entirely.

In reality, there are many "black" rectangles and thousands of "reds", I'm looking for an effective algorithm to calculate. I have to implement this in ECMA-/Javascript so it's not really the fastest of all platforms.

I looked into some algos like Richard E. Korf's "Optimal Rectangle Packing" or "Bin packings problems", but I couldn't really translate those for this specific problem.

Can somebody recommend me a method/algorithm ?

Comment: This sounds like knapsack problem.

Comment: since the widths are all the same, you can simplify the problem to 1-dimension

Comment: Are the sizes of the rectangle integer? How big are they (can the height go up to billion scale)?

Comment: A couple followup questions: 1) What is the context of the problem? Is it okay to have a 'mostly optimal' solution at the expense of 100% correctness? 2) You say 'many' black rectangles... is it a possibly unbounded number of black rectangles? Or a constant number? What is the approximate ratio of red to black, and red area to black area? 3) What is the criteria of acceptability? Is it for a business  purpose where if it's close enough that's okay? Or is it for an academic purpose where the real criteria is formulating the algorithm not solving a business need.

Comment: @corsiKa: 1) && 3), its on business purpose, its about auto-spreading advertisments into columns, losing as less space as possible. So, the 'greedy' approach to get the perfect result for column #1 is not necesesarrily the best, leaving the other columns with more "open space". Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: @jAndy are larger ads worth more revenue? What is the relationship between size of the ad and your revenue? Clearly you'd rather show the ads that make you the most money!

Comment: @corsiKa: it's not purely business yet, its more a tech-demo and we want to see how fast javascript performs and this calculation point. So the rule remains, just using available space as effective as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your red and black triangles both have a defined width, you can reduce the problem to a number line, so to speak. Basically, if you ever flipped a red one on its side, you'd most likely end up with wasted space - much more wasted space than putting it in the 'normal fitting' way.

So with this in mind, you can reduce the problem exactly to the traditional knapsack problem where the capacity is the height of the black rectangle and the 'weight' of the red triangles are their height. The width can be entirely abstracted out of the problem.

Another advantage (as pointed out by xvatar) is that the value density of the candidates are all equal. That is to say that you don't have the "brick-ring" issue the traditional knapsack problem has. Given the choice between bricks and rings to fill your knapsack with, the rings are obvious candidates. In this case, they're all the same so there are no obvious candidates.

It would seem the big blocks are easy candidates, but this greedy approach doesn't fly. Consider the scenario where there are 5 units of space left, and we have bricks of 4, 3 and 2. If we go with the greedy solution, we add the 4, leaving 1 open space. If we would instead have gone with 3 and 2, we would not have the 1 open space remaining.

It also stands to note that once you have identified what rectangles go in, it doesn't matter what order they go in.

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: not sure if it's a typical knapsack problem, here "value" and "weight" are both the "height"

Comment: @xvatar It is a special case of the knapsack problem where value density is constant among candidates, which greatly simplifies the problem. I'll edit to include this distinction.

Comment: I fooled around with the knapsack-algo already, but couldn't solve the problem in a very satisfying way so far. I think your answer helps a lot, I'll be on the drawing board tomorrow :-)

Comment: If I wrote something in Java, would you be capable of converting it into JavaScript? I'm not really a js guy, but I'm willing to bet what few structures I would use in Java are available for you conceptually in JS.

Comment: @jAndy Would you be able to supply a pastebin of reds and blacks? Like actual data you might be using? Just the integer values of their size will suffice.

Comment: @jAndy - When I was testing this out, I found that a simple, greedy algorithm was incredibly effective. It usually filled all the black boxes in a single pass through the list of reds. Here's my java code - I don't know how much I messed with it AFTER I had it working, so take it with a grain of salt. It was two weeks ago, after all. :) http://pastebin.com/QGtfzkST

Comment: @corsiKa: thanks for the code, I will have a look. At first glance, it looks like you're not optimizing anything really. By just looking if there is any *red* which fits the available space, you're ignoring the possibilty that using a partial or entire set of *red blocks* it might fit the space better or completely.

Comment: Like I said, a simple pass fills it. Because the set of *reds* are sorted, I know I get the biggest first. I had written more advanced passes (aptly named `advancedPass` and `moreAdvancedPass`) that checked for filling the space available. But, what I found was that there was almost never any empty space to fill! The simple pass consistently and completely filled the entire black box! I was astounded, which was why I followed up asking for real world data. But then even with that real data, it still worked perfectly.